# Can't get gata using arrow function in Vue

Tags: typescript, api, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I am new in Vue, my problem: i can't get data from API to my component.
I have a service class that get's data from my api. Api works fine. So code:

```
import IReview from "../types/Review"
import axios from "axios"

export default class ReviewService{
    API_URL=process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;
 
    public async getAllReviews(id: number): Promise<IReview[]>{
        const result=await axios.get(`${this.API_URL}/film/${id}/reviews`);
        console.log(result.data, "This is ok, i see my data in console")
        return result.data;
    }
}
```

Who wants to know, I get film reviews from API, using filmId.

Get result is fine [Img](https://prnt.sc/uhttae)

So my component which it get:

```
<template>
    <div class="ComentsField">
        <div class="ListOfComments">
            <div v-if="this.getReviewsCount()>0">
                <review :review="review"
                 v-for="review in ReviewsList" 
                 v-bind:key="review.id" 
                 v-bind:FilmId="FilmId">
                        {{review.Review}}
                </review>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="AddNewComment">
            Add
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import ReviewService from '@/services/review-service.ts'
import IReview from '@/types/Review.d.ts'
import  Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import Review from '@/components/Review.vue'

const reviewService=new ReviewService();
@Component({
    props: ['FilmId'],
 name: 'Reviews',
 components: {Review}
})
export default class Reviews extends Vue{
    ReviewsList: IReview[]=[];
    getReviewsCount(){
        return this.ReviewsList.length;
    }
    getAllReviews(){
        console.log(this.ReviewsList.length, "**IT gets me zero**")
        reviewService.getAllReviews(this.$props['FilmId']).then(data=>this.ReviewsList=data).catch(err=>console.error(err));
        console.log(this.ReviewsList, "1111111111s")//undef  BUT WHY i import data
        console.log(this.ReviewsList.length, "222222")//0 again
    }
    created()
    {
        this.getAllReviews();
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

IReview

```
export default interface IReview
{
    id:number,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn:Date,
    Review: string,
    ReviewAuthor: string,
}
```

In console log i comment what's happen.

Of couse i push this into a github and u can find here (BackEnd .NET 5).

[GitHub](https://github.com/andr1312e/My-Favorite-Films/tree/for-releases)

I have no ideas why it happen, and will be glad to any help.

Comment: move those two `console.log` into the callback of `getAllReviews.then()`. Ex: `reviewService.getAllReviews(...).then((data) => console.log(this.ReviewsList))`

Comment: I'm not familiar with TS, but unless I'm missing something releated to that, you shouln't modify directly the value of `ReviewList`, but access to it by means of mutations and/or action dispatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer**: your console.log is executed before the http promise is actually resolved. So you print out your variable but you don't have your result yet.

**Solution**: Move your console.log into the `.then()` block or use `async/await` the same way you did in your service.

Additional improvements: Transform your `getReviewsCount` into a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Comment: Ok i will try tomorrow and will answer

Comment: hi again, it dont help. I get undef in my Review component Again

Comment: I guess it worked since you approved my answer?
Also, you should wrap you then statement into parenthesis like so: `.then(data=>(this.ReviewsList=data))`

Answer (score 0):

I am solve it
Who want's to know i fix my review class

```
  props: ["review", "FilmId"],
```

And make some fix in my Reviews v-for

```
<div class="ListOfComments">
  <div v-if="this.getReviewsCount()>0">
    <div v-for="review in ReviewsList" v-bind:key="review.id">
      Вошли в цикл
      <review :review="review" :FilmId="FilmId">
        Пытаемся писать ревью
        {{review.Review}}
      </review>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find more example on the doc :

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

and for axios here :
https://github.com/axios/axios#example

Comment: hi, i have a error with props, axios works fine thanks